# Uncaught ReferenceError: pyeval is not defined

Tags: odoo, export-to-excel, odoo-10

When I click **Export XLSX** on the **General Ledger** I get the error : **pyeval is not defined**

[image]

any idea how can I deal with it ?

after adding the `debug=assets` on the url I got :

```
http://localhost:8069/web_pdf_preview/static/src/js/web_pdf_preview.js:117
Retraçage :
ReferenceError: pyeval is not defined
    at Class.ir_actions_report_xml (http://localhost:8069/web_pdf_preview/static/src/js/web_pdf_preview.js:117:30)
    at Class.ir_actions_report_xml (http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/framework/class.js:122:38)
    at Class.do_action (http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/action_manager.js:672:33)
    at Class.do_action (http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/framework/widget.js:409:37)
    at Class.do_action (http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/framework/widget.js:409:37)
    at Class.do_action (http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/framework/widget.js:409:37)
    at Object.handler (http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/framework/view.js:97:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:3276:89)
    at fire (http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:3119:58)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:3231:49)
```

Comment: Add `debug=assets` on your url and try again. Then post the stack trace for us to see.

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas I added the stack trace

Answer (score 2):

solved the problem by adding declaring the variable **pyeval** on the file: *web_pdf_preview/static/src/js/web_pdf_preview.js*

```
var pyeval = require('web.pyeval');
```